# Problema CORS de fetch() en Chrome, pero que no ocurre en Firefox en un proyecto de React Vite

Tags: reactjs, fetch, cors, google-chrome, vite

Tengo un proyecto en ReactJS Vite en local donde intento hacer fetch a un endpoint que realizó un compañero en Laravel, pero me da problemas CORS en Chrome, pero no en Firefox. Veo en internet que se puede configurar de alguna manera las cabeceras o un proxy, pero tampoco me resultan, ya que he intentado con variasa cabeceras y ninguna funciona y el proxy no me lo toma. Alguien sabe una forma de solucionarlo sin tener que configurar el CORS en el backend de Laravel?

Los códigos del vite.config.js, del fetch():

```
export default defineConfig({
  root: new URL('.', import.meta.url).pathname,
  build: {
    outDir: './dist'
  },
  server: {
    port: 8080,
  },
  base: '/',
})
```

```
fetch("http://akikb.skymedia.works/api/token", {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
            'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
        }})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
```